# How do I prevent a MacOS WebView from losing first responder after hitting tab?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, webview

My app has a WebView within a SplitView, displaying a few HTML tables. It uses javascript to move between these tables using the TAB key. However, after hitting tab once the webView is no longer selected and the app selects another pane of my app to continue listening to tab events.

1) Is there a way to prevent this behavior?
2) Is this the default behavior of hitting tab on a WebView, or is there something else going on in my app that is reassigning the first responder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `nextKeyView` to return `nil` in any class for which you want to keep the first responder despite pressing <kbd>tab</kbd>.

**However**, this will make your app harder to navigate, especially using accessibility. I instead recommend using a key other than <kbd>tab</kbd> to trigger moving between tables.

Comment: This worked in the view holding the WebView:
`override var nextKeyView: NSView? {
        get {
          return nil
        }
        set {
           super.nextKeyView = newValue
        }
    }
    
    override var previousKeyView: NSView? {
        get {
            return nil
        }
    }`